# ErrorType: database is not a function Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jsx

I want connect with my database and when I write this code I get this error:

> TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.database is not a function

```
    createNote() {
    if (this.state.title !== '' && this.state.note !== '') {
        firebase.database().ref('notes').push({       (probably in this line is error console say)
            title: this.state.title,
            note: this.state.note
        })
    }
}
```

index.js:

```
    import firebase from "firebase/app";

    const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
........
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

package.js

```
 "dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.0",
"firebase": "^8.2.6",                     (I only this add)
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.2",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
```

},

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This depends on how you import firebase (in your code) and how you added the dependency (likely to your package.json) file. Can you edit your question to show both?

Comment: edited the post, hope i put everything right here. Also I am using Realtime Database in firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only import you currently have for Firebase is:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
```

This imports only the basic SDK that allows you to initialize the `firebase` object. It does not import any product-specific SDKs.

To use the Realtime Database, you also need to import that SDK with:

```
import "firebase/database";
```

Comment: Yes yes yes :D thank you. This working now